# Entity Framework Core: How do I load data when a view model is created?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a Blazor component (although it might as well be a Razor page, WPF view etc for the purposes of my question) that allows the user to create a new entity.

The component injects a view model, which exposes properties that the component binds to form controls. When the user clicks a button on the component, it calls a method on the view model that saves the entity to the database.

This is all working fine.

The problem I have is that I need to add a property whose value is to be chosen from a collection, using a dropdown (think HTML's `<select>` or Blazor's `InputSelect`). I need to load the collection from the database, so that the dropdown on the component can display the values, and allow the user to choose one.

However, as EF is all async, I can't load the data in the view model constructor.

I did get around it by adding a view model method to load the data, and calling that from the component's `OnInitializedAsync()` method...

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() =>
  await ViewModel.LoadData();
```

...but makes me wonder if I'm just doing this wrong. Is there a way that the view model can load the data on its own?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

> However, as EF is all async, I can't load the data in the view model
> constructor.

Actually you can, using the `Task.Wait()` method, like -

```
public MyViewModel()
{
     this.SomeList = SomeDataLoadingMethodSomewhereAsync().Wait();
}
```

I think you get the idea. You are calling an async method, and waiting on it until it returns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try that, but it felt wrong somehow.